# Need to get value of space from parent element in pixels

Tags: jquery

I need your quick help. I have a list of 'li'. I have 10 LIs In the UL. I need to get how many pixel every LI is away from left(UL).

Thanks :)

Comment: are you implying their relative position in the html content or on screen?

Comment: yes in the html content

Comment: <ul>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
<li></li>
</ul>

Comment: post a fiddle showing what you've tried

Comment: i did not tried anything yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you'd like to iterate through each li and get its left offset.

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/LkTdD/

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
    <li>List Item</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(function(){
    $('li').each(function(index,el){
        var offset = $(el).offset();
        var html = $(el).html();
        $(el).html(html + ' ' + offset.left);
    });
});
```

Best regards,

Comment: That's because they all have the same offset from the left of the document.